# Swift - Mapping invisible button on UIImage which zoom In/Out

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, mapping

Can some one suggest the best way to do this..

In the Below Image

- Add invisible buttons over the image for each section of the map.
- The image should be in a scrollview to zoom in and out the image.
- Zooming in/out should not change the button mapping area
- Should support for all iPhone models.

[image]

**What I did..**

Added a UIImageView inside a UIScrollView(for zoom in/out) and on viewDidAppear() manually added invisible button for the UIImage like this.

```
self.image.frame = CGRect(x: xValue , y:yValue, width: 60, height: 60)
```

Is there any better solution for finding the UIImage coordinates?

Comment: In the screenshot you provided, are these multiple buttons? Please explain your requirement a bit more clearly.

Comment: This is an image. I need to add invisible button on each image and should keep the aspect ratio of the image even if we zoom in/out.

Comment: Why don't you add tap gesture to uIimageview ?

Comment: If it is collectionview then use didSeelectItemAtIndexPath delegate of collectionview

Comment: Its an UIImageView inside a UIScrollView and i need to add 9 invisible button on each block. When i zoom in or out the invisible button should keep the ratio.

Comment: Okay @Barath, Then Any special purpose to use UIButton ?. Same thing you can achieve using tap gesture

Comment: Yeah tap gesture is another solution. My main concern is finding the coordinates of the image. And when i add the coordinates manually it shows different output in different iPhone models

Comment: you can achieve this using collection view, instead of finding coordinates, in didSelect you can do the rest

Comment: This map will not work with a collection view :(

Comment: So I guess what you are trying to do is to be able to tap on each 'room' in the image have have some functionality occur.  First is the image dynamic at runtime or available at design time.  What I am asking is how do you slice the image up into sections that need different actions?

Comment: I cannot slice up the image. But is there a way to find the coordinates of the images to get exact x and y axis and draw a invisible image at the point. The point should not change as per the iPhone models as well. When i hard code and draw a button in view did appear, it appears different on different models

Answer (score 0):

Very late to the party, but this should work:

in `ViewDidLoad` add this:

```
    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.5
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 6.0
    scrollView.contentSize = self.imageView.frame.size
    scrollView.delegate = self
```

After `ViewDidLoad` add this:

```
// MARK: - Update the minimum zoom scale each time the controller updates its subviews
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    updateMinZoomScaleForSize(view.bounds.size)
}
```

Then create a file private function to calculate the zoom scale for scrollView

```
fileprivate func updateMinZoomScaleForSize(_ size: CGSize) {
    let widthScale = size.width / imageView.bounds.width
    let heightScale = size.height / imageView.bounds.height
    let minScale = min(widthScale, heightScale)

    imageScrollView.minimumZoomScale = minScale
    imageScrollView.zoomScale = minScale
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Are you using nine imageViews? No. it's not correct it seems.

Try like this :

1. Take a **collection view** and give necessary constraints like top, bottom, left and right.
2. Add image view to collection view cell. Add corner radius properties(it seems ur image views need this).
3. For zoom in and zoom out actions, add pinch gesture to collection view.
4. Add **tap gesture** for image view, instead of buttons.

Comment: This is just a sample image and I am using different image like a floor map. So cannot use a UICollectionView. So if you have a solution for the mapping image coordinates, kindly let me know

Comment: What is the point of the collection view in this answer?  What is it being used for?  It appears to be being used for no apparent reason.

Comment: I added a confusing image at first, thats why he told about the collection view. My bad :(.